# Screen brightness not dimming before screen blank on ubuntu 22.10

Tags: brightness, backlight, 22.10

I tried to dim screen brightness below minimum.
did change values in /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness....

now screen brightness is not dimming before screen goes blank on ubuntu 22.10. it goes blank suddenly.

How to make it normal now?

Comment: Why would you set it below min?

Comment: i want less brightness when i turn off my room light.

Comment: I believe you cause the issue trying to do something weird, below min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem reseting Gnome desktop settings to factory defaults using dconf.
`$ dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`

exact cause of issue is not known